# Choosing pairs and singles out of $n$ students

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $n$ different students, find the number of ways to divide them to $k$ pairs, and $n-2k$ "singles". No order in pairs/singles.

So my idea was to first choose $n-2k$ singles, then out of all possible pairs in the $2k$ students who are now determined, choose $k$ pairs. i.e $\binom{n}{n-2k} \binom{\binom{2k}{2}}{k}$ but this does not seem to work. where is my mistake? the solution my teacher gave is $\frac{n!}{(n-2k)!k!2^k}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $k$ pairs may overlap, so you are not dividing into $k$ pairs.

The correct way of selecting $k$ pairs, is to order the $2k$ elements in one of $(2k)!$ ways, and pair off adjacent elements (first and second, third and fourth etc.).  Note that we get the same pairing by swapping any adjacent pair in our ordering.  Also note that rearranging the $k$ adjacent pairs in any of $k!$ ways also results in the same pairing.  Thus we have $$\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$$ ways of pairing up the $2k$ elements.  Here by adjacent we mean an odd positioned element and its successor.

Multiplying by the factor you already calculated, for the number of ways of choosing the singles, results in your teachers answer.